# Can memorystore Redis be used to store session data of flask app running on App Engine?

Tags: flask, session, redis, flask-login

I have a flask application on App Engine, where I am trying to find a suitable solution to store the user session data.

I came across redis as a solution [please suggest if anything suites better], I am still figuring out on how I can use the Memeorystore Redis to store the session data.

I am trying to use the flask login manager along with memorystore to make this work.

Following is my code:

I am encountering error at line "login_user(user)"

```
app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'redis'
app.config['SESSION_PERMANENT'] = False
app.config['SESSION_USE_SIGNER'] = True
app.config['SESSION_KEY_PREFIX'] = 'tank_userSession0782328'  # Change this to a unique prefix
REDIS_HOST = os.getenv('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost')
REDIS_PORT = int(os.getenv('REDIS_PORT', 6379))
app.config['SESSION_REDIS'] = redis.StrictRedis(host=REDIS_HOST, port=REDIS_PORT)

Session(app)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = "login"
login_manager.init_app(app)

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login_authentication():
    try:
        # Get the username and password from the request
        username = request.json.get('username')
        password = request.json.get('password')

        # Validate the login credentials
        user = validate_credentials(username, password)

        if user:
            # Log the login details in the 'login_sheetName' sheet
            log_login_details(user.id, username)

            login_user(user)

            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            # Return an error response
            print("Login credentials mismatch")
            return jsonify({'error': 'Invalid username or password'})
        
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", e)
        return jsonify({'error': 'An error occurred'})
```

Google cloud error logs look like:

> DEFAULT 2023-11-10T13:45:01.924336Z [2023-11-10 13:45:01,918] ERROR in app: Exception on /login [POST]
> ERROR 2023-11-10T13:45:01.924365Z Traceback (most recent call last): File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request()
> DEFAULT 2023-11-10T13:45:01.924369Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> DEFAULT 2023-11-10T13:45:01.924376Z File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1487, in full_dispatch_request
> DEFAULT 2023-11-10T13:45:01.924380Z return self.finalize_request(rv)
> DEFAULT 2023-11-10T13:45:01.924384Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> DEFAULT 2023-11-10T13:45:01.924388Z File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1508, in finalize_request
> DEFAULT 2023-11-10T13:45:01.924393Z response = self.process_response(response)
> DEFAULT 2023-11-10T13:45:01.924397Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> DEFAULT 2023-11-10T13:45:01.924402Z File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2005, in process_response
> DEFAULT 2023-11-10T13:45:01.924406Z self.session_interface.save_session(self, ctx.session, response)
> DEFAULT 2023-11-10T13:45:01.924411Z File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_session/sessions.py", line 161, in save_session
> DEFAULT 2023-11-10T13:45:01.924415Z session_id = self._get_signer(app).sign(want_bytes(session.sid))
> DEFAULT 2023-11-10T13:45:01.924419Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> DEFAULT 2023-11-10T13:45:01.927387Z AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sign'
> DEFAULT 2023-11-10T13:45:01.927401Z [2023-11-10 13:45:01,926] ERROR in app: Request finalizing failed with an error while handling an error